# Errors when using RSA function to encrypt a string

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I am new to encryption and I am trying to encrypt a string using RSA function, with a public key saved in pubkey.pem .
After running the following Python script

```
import rsa

# Load the public key
with open('pubkey.pem', 'rb') as key_file:
    key_data = key_file.read()
public_key = rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1(key_data)

# Encrypt the string using the public key
   message = b"Abiodun"
   encrypted_message = rsa.encrypt(message, public_key)

 # Print the encrypted message
  print(encrypted_message)
```

I get this error

```
 raise ValueError('No PEM start marker "%r" found' % pem_start)
 ValueError: No PEM start marker "b'-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----'" found
```

Not sure what im doing wrong or how to fix it. the public key seem to be in the right structure and Starts with

```
 BEGIN PUBLIC KEY
```

Comment: Your public key has the X.509/SPKI format, try [`load_pkcs1_openssl_pem()`](https://stuvel.eu/python-rsa-doc/reference.html#rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1_openssl_pem) instead of `load_pkcs1()`.